# How to set Wifi state using WifiManager in class derived from ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2?

Tags: android, automated-tests, instrumentation

I have automated UI android instrumentation tests that need to turn on/off Wifi for specific test cases.  I thought this would be a piece of cake but I am having some trouble.  I need to have the permissions for turning on/off system services in the manifest APK for my test code.  I don't want to modify the manifest for the app I am testing.

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml for my test code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application android:label="UI Tests">
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner"/>
</application>

<instrumentation android:name="com.mycompany.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
                 android:targetPackage="com.mycompany"
                 android:label="UI Tests"/>
```

When I see the test apk installed, it definitely has all these permissions on the actual device.

Now here's the code where I try to set the Wifi state...

```
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getInstrumentation().getContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if ((!wifiEnabled) && (wifi.getWifiState() != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED)){
        mTestLogger.logMsg("Turning off wifi");
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
        sleep(3000);
    }
```

I thought this code was correct.  getInstrumenation().getContext() is the context of the apk for the test code.  However when it hits the line with wifi.setWifiEnabled(false) it throws an exception:

java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10145 nor current process has android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE.

Any idea what I did wrong?  The manifest clearly has CHANGE_WIFI_STATE and I confirmed on the device that the permission is set correctly.

I must have the wrong context.  getInstrumentation().getContext().getApplicationInfo() gives me the correct information for my test apk.  So it looks right to me.

Comment: one more piece of the puzzle.  I wondered if I should use getInstrumentation().getContext().getApplicationContext(), but that returns null.

Comment: I think the answer lies in the fact that the AndroidManifest.xml for the test apk doesn't seem to have any effect.  I read this comment elsewhere: "test is never more privileged than application. Both are run inside the same process - only separate threads - so I suppose permissions from application are end permissions for process."

Comment: After I added the android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE to the manifest for the application itself, the test code was able to turn off the Wifi.  So I think that comment I read was correct.  You can only use the permissions in the application manifest, not the test manifest.

Answer (score 2):

This makes sense. A `Context` carries with it a set of permissions. Per your explanation, `getInstrumentation().getContext()` returns the context of the app being tested and therefore that app's permissions. If you use that context to manipulate wifi and the app has no appropriate permissions, the operation will fail regardless of your own permissions.